# Debug 30sec+ TTFB on WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to debug extremely high frontend page generation times on a WordPress 5.3.2 site.

Here is sample data from the debug bar for a frontend page:

```
Page Generation Time 30.9443 seconds
Database Query Time 0.0269 seconds
Actions Execution time: 1207.07ms
Slowest Action: 301.86ms
```

As you can see, our total actions and database queries aren't even 1.5 seconds, yet our page generation time is 30.94 seconds in this example.

To be clear: ~30sec is the time it takes the client to even receive the HTML document from the server (TTFB), *not* the time it takes to request and download all page resources.

Viewing pages in wp-admin itself is fine; the extreme delay only happens viewing  frontend pages.

I'm trying to identify what is causing the rest of the delay before the document is served to the client.

Environment Details:

- Ubuntu 18.04, Nginx, PHP 7.4, and MySQL 8.0
- The server itself has plenty of available CPU (2 vCPU cores) and memory (4GB+8GB swap), as verified via tools like `glances` and `top`. We have other PHP applications (phpMyAdmin and a Laravel application) running on this server without issue.

---

#### What I've tried

- disabling all plugins, one by one
- install W3 Total Cache (W3TC) with all cache types enabled
- reinstall WP 5.3.2 (from wp-admin, not manually)
- check `wp-config.php` for signs of malware

Nothing so far has helped (not even W3TC) or pointed to a potential cause.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it would get a better answer on either [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) or [wordpress.se]. (Just thought - have you a time-out accessing 3rd-party JavaScript widgets, etc?)

Comment: 30s looks like an external HTTP connection timeout, check your theme files

Comment: Thank you! I found requests to a remote MySQL db in one of the child theme files. It was added a long time ago, and that MySQL server is no longer active. Hence the timeout.

Comment: @Nathan If you are all well now, how can you mark this question 'Closed'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the suggestion of @user1597430, I checked the child theme files and found requests to a remote MySQL server in one of them. That code was added a long time ago, and the MySQL server is no longer active. Hence the delay and eventual timeout.